# VBA code to send email through gmail with pdf attachment

Tags: vba, email, pdf, gmail

I have this code that is already working, but not 100%... I would like to send an email through Gmail with a pdf attached... But I don´t want a specific pdf file.

I know I can put a specific file name on the code, but my pdf files always change the name

Example: 
`Clientname_1.pdf, Clientmane_2.pdf, Suppliername_1.pdf, etc`

The code I have is this, but does not work:

```
Dim objEmail, objConfig
Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

objEmail.From = "xpto@gmail.com"
objEmail.To =     Join(Application.Transpose(Sheets("Clients").Columns(7).SpecialCells(2)), ";")
objEmail.Subject = "Test"
objEmail.CC = ""
objEmail.AddAttachment "C:\Users\123\Desktop\*.pdf"
```

I need that the code go to the folder I want and send the existing pdf file(s) on it......

What is missing in this code???

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking for the first .PDF file found then something like this would be appropriate.

```
dim dr as string
dr = "C:\Users\123\Desktop\"
objEmail.AddAttachment dr & Dir(dr & "*.pdf")
```

The [Dir function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278779.aspx) could loop and find all appropriate matches but it seems that you only want the first one. If Dir cannot find a matching file it will return a zero-length string.

For additional functionality, you might want to use the [Environ function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fx287h4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to get the current user's profile folder and get their Desktop folder from there.